# WAMP server with the custom URL

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

I want to keep my WAMP server URL as xyz.local, which can be allow from all my Network.
my server IP address is 192.168.1.50 and it work on port 8080.

I made the setting as -
on the host file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   xyz.local
```

on the httpd.conf file

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

ServerName localhost:8080
ServerName xyz.local:8080
```

on the httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName xyz.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Now from all the computer in my network I can access the page as `http://192.168.1.50:8080`

and from the WAMP server computer I can access as `http://192.168.1.50:8080` and `http://xyz.local:8080`

If I try to access the page as `http://xyz.local:8080` from another computer I got a message as "This page can't be displayed"

Please help me out with my error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you ping xyz.local from other computers on your network?
If the ping command doesn't resolve that name to the correct IP, you'll either need to add it to your router, or each of your computer's hosts files.

Comment: I can ping it from my server computer itself. but can not ping from the another computer. Please guide me.

Comment: You can ping it on your server computer because you have added it to the hosts file on your server computer. The other computers have no way of knowing where that name points to. You can either add it to your router settings (consult manual for your router model if you need to), or you can add to the hosts file of the other computers:
192.168.1.50  xyz.local

Comment: Good stuff, glad to help :)

Comment: In my network there is total 47 computers and it very difficult for me to change all th HOSTs files. I try to configure in my router but there is no option for it. I am using a router DNA-A211-I